Activation Code for Trackmania on UBISOFT CONNECT
I just installed Trackmania from Steam which is a "Free To Play" game according to the Steam page.
Once I opened the game, it started installing "UBISOFT CONNECT" and now it's asking for an "ACTIVATION CODE" after I signed into UBISOFT CONNECT:


So is Trackmania not actually "Free To Play"? Do I need to buy it somewhere?
I checked my emails and I don't see an Activation Code there either.

Ah.
Looks like I just needed to re-open the game for a second time.
The second time I opened the game, Ubisoft Connected gave a popup saying that the game was now registered to my account, and then afterwards the game successfully opened.

Alternatively. Some people recommended that you should try and redeem the game on Ubisoft Connect's website:
https://steamcommunity.com/app/2225070/discussions/0/3879345732189144846/
https://steamcommunity.com/app/2225070/discussions/1/3879345732187267285/
